# How to parse nested JSON using custom completion block with JSONDecoder?

Tags: ios, json, swift

i have nested json object, and need to parse and take fill out the collectionViewCell with imageUrls in the json
[i need to iterate overe list.recommendBannerImages and save it in external var so that i can use it into my collectionViewCells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFmww.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post images of your code. There are [several reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6612182) that this is not encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you write a function for this and lets assume that this function name fetchData and your data model should be conform Codable protocol.

```
func fetchData(url: String, completion: @escaping(Result<[DataModel], Error>)->()){
guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            completion(.failure(error!))
            print(error!)
        } else{
            guard let _ = response as? HTTPURLResponse, let jsonData = data  else { return }
            let yourDataModel = try? JSONDecoder().decode([DataModel].self, from: jsonData)
            guard let dataModels = mainPageContentData else { return } //dataModels is array of DataModel
            completion(.success(dataModels)) // And we send this array to completion blocks
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

And you should use this function like this

```
        fetchData { (result) in //Trailing closure syntax
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case .success(let datas):
            for data in datas{
              print(data)
              }
         }
     }
```

Comment: yeah all my objects confirm Codable, but what i am asking is that I am retrieving data inside of nested json objects, so i dont need all data. Thats why, in tvRecomendation_fetch i am fetching the RecommendBannerImagesModel and then in closure i want to pass it in fetch() method. in that case how can i loop over each RecommendBannerImagesModel object, and for each i need to cast imageUrls?

Comment: sorry i can't understand clearly can you share the code?